# Как разместить MessageBox по центру окна в Windows Forms и WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, messagebox

Чтобы отцентрировать попап диалог по центру родительского окна, можно реализовать свой диалог, и использовать его вместо `MessageBox`. Но иногда это лишнее, надо по-простому и привычному, а также если есть старый проект, можно улучшить его поведение не затратив много времени на доработку.

`MessageBox` по умолчанию выскакивает в центре экрана, а как его сделать по центру окна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готового способа нет, Windows не поддерживает такие фокусы. Но можно реализовать самому.

У меня есть давно реализованное решение, назвал его `MessageBoxEx`, решил поделиться.

Класс `MessageBoxEx` требует для WPF требует наличия установленного NuGet пакета `System.Drawing.Common`. В Winforms этот пакет подключен по умолчанию, поэтому установка не требуется.

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Вот готовые классы:

#### Windows Forms

```
public static class MessageBoxEx
{
    private static Form _owner;
    private static readonly HookProc _hookProc = new HookProc(MessageBoxHookProc);
    private static IntPtr _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static DialogResult Show(Form owner, string text)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(Form owner, string text, string caption)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(Form owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(Form owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(Form owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defButton)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon, defButton);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(Form owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defButton, MessageBoxOptions options)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon, defButton, options);
    }

    private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12;

    private enum CbtHookAction : int
    {
        HCBT_MOVESIZE = 0,
        HCBT_MINMAX = 1,
        HCBT_QS = 2,
        HCBT_CREATEWND = 3,
        HCBT_DESTROYWND = 4,
        HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5,
        HCBT_CLICKSKIPPED = 6,
        HCBT_KEYSKIPPED = 7,
        HCBT_SYSCOMMAND = 8,
        HCBT_SETFOCUS = 9
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct CWPRETSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr lResult;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public CbtHookAction message;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
    };

    private static void Initialize(Form owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        if (owner is Form form && form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            if (_hHook != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Multiple calls are not supported");
            }

            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, _hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr MessageBoxHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        CWPRETSTRUCT msg = Marshal.PtrToStructure<CWPRETSTRUCT>(lParam);
        IntPtr hook = _hHook;

        if (msg.message == CbtHookAction.HCBT_ACTIVATE)
        {
            try
            {
                CenterWindow(msg.hwnd);
            }
            finally
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hHook);
                _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private static void CenterWindow(IntPtr hChildWnd)
    {
        if (_owner is Form form)
        {
            Rectangle recChild = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            _ = GetWindowRect(hChildWnd, ref recChild);

            int width = recChild.Width - recChild.X;
            int height = recChild.Height - recChild.Y;

            int x = form.Left + ((form.Width - width) / 2);
            int y = form.Top + ((form.Height - height) / 2);

            _ = MoveWindow(hChildWnd, x, y, width, height, false);
        }
    }
}
```

#### WPF

```
public static class MessageBoxEx
{
    private static Window _owner;
    private static readonly HookProc _hookProc = new HookProc(MessageBoxHookProc);
    private static IntPtr _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string text)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text);
    }

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string text, string caption)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption);
    }

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButton buttons)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons);
    }

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButton buttons, MessageBoxImage icon)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon);
    }

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButton buttons, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defButton)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon, defButton);
    }

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButton buttons, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defButton, MessageBoxOptions options)
    {
        Initialize(owner);
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon, defButton, options);
    }

    private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12;

    private enum CbtHookAction : int
    {
        HCBT_MOVESIZE = 0,
        HCBT_MINMAX = 1,
        HCBT_QS = 2,
        HCBT_CREATEWND = 3,
        HCBT_DESTROYWND = 4,
        HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5,
        HCBT_CLICKSKIPPED = 6,
        HCBT_KEYSKIPPED = 7,
        HCBT_SYSCOMMAND = 8,
        HCBT_SETFOCUS = 9
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct CWPRETSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr lResult;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public CbtHookAction message;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
    };

    private static void Initialize(Window owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        if (owner is Window window && window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        {
            if (_hHook != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Multiple calls are not supported");
            }

            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, _hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr MessageBoxHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        CWPRETSTRUCT msg = Marshal.PtrToStructure<CWPRETSTRUCT>(lParam);
        IntPtr hook = _hHook;

        if (msg.message == CbtHookAction.HCBT_ACTIVATE)
        {
            try
            {
                CenterWindow(msg.hwnd);
            }
            finally
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hHook);
                _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private static void CenterWindow(IntPtr hChildWnd)
    {
        if (_owner is Window window)
        {
            Rectangle recChild = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            _ = GetWindowRect(hChildWnd, ref recChild);

            int width = recChild.Width - recChild.X;
            int height = recChild.Height - recChild.Y;

            PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window);
            double scaleX = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
            double scaleY = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;

            int x = (int)((window.Left + (window.Width - width / scaleX) / 2) * scaleX);
            int y = (int)((window.Top + (window.Height - height / scaleY) / 2) * scaleY);

            _ = MoveWindow(hChildWnd, x, y, width, height, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Оба класса, как можно заметить почти одинаковые, но адаптированы под нужный UI движок.

#### Использование

Точно так же как обычный `MessageBox`, только первым параметром передать окно (или форму), относительно которого его надо отцентрирвоать.

Использование одинаково для Winforms и WPF:

```
MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Hello World");
```

где `this` это `Form` для Winforms, либо `Window` для WPF.

Comment: ♦ WPF. Это можно использовать в MVVM? Я так понимаю предполагается,  вызывать MessageBoxEx нужно из ВьюМодел ?

Comment: @eusataf почему бы и нет. Сделайте обертку, какой-нибудь класс MessageDialog, инициализируйте его с экземпляром окна и передайте во вьюмодель готовый к работе. А с вьюмодели передавайте только тексты   конфигурации диалогов.